# popup a message dialog with return value

Tags: c#, uwp

I am a newbie of c# & uwp

my code to popup a message dialog is

```
    private void messageBoxClick(IUICommand command)
    {
        // Display message showing the label of the command that was invoked
        //rootPage.NotifyUser("The '" + command.Label + "' command has been selected.", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
    }

    public async Task messageBoxShow(string s, string commandString1, string commandString2)
    {
        var dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(s);
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand(commandString1, new UICommandInvokedHandler(this.messageBoxClick)));
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand(commandString2, new UICommandInvokedHandler(this.messageBoxClick)));

        await dialog.ShowAsync();


    }
```

it works!
but the style I hope to get is

```
    string s = messageBoxShow(s, commandString1, commandString2);
```

Is it possible to change the former style to this one

Your comment welcome

Comment: Current version of `messageBoxShow` doesn't try to return a string, what value do you plan to return from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The display of `MessageDialog` is an asynchronous operation, and the result returned by `ShowAsync` is `IUICommand`. If the string value you want to get is `IUICommand.Label`, you can write like this:

```cs
public async Task<string> messageBoxShow(string s, string commandString1, string commandString2)
{
    var dialog = new MessageDialog(s);
    dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand(commandString1, new UICommandInvokedHandler(this.messageBoxClick)));
    dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand(commandString2, new UICommandInvokedHandler(this.messageBoxClick)));
    var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
    return result.Label;
}
```

**Usage**

```cs
string label = await messageBoxShow(s, commandString1, commandString2);
```